# Auto change page title while bookmarking a page

Tags: javascript, browser, keyboard

I want to change the page title while use try to add the page to bookmark (ctrl+D).

Here is what I'm trying:

```
function quicklyChangePageTitle() {
  var currentTitle = document.title; // remember original title
  document.title = "temp title"; // change to the temporary title

  setTimeout(function() { // revert back to original title
    document.title = currentTitle;
  }, 1);

}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 68) { // Ctrl + D
    quicklyChangePageTitle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Does it solve the case, or is there another issue?

Comment: @user13500 this code works but I planned not to use such code. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44029/auto-change-page-title-while-bookmarking-a-page/44030?noredirect=1#44030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but there is one problem and that is the time.

`setTimeout()` uses milliseconds. As such:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.title = currentTitle;
}, 1);
```

would set the title back after 1ms.

So to set it to e.g. 5 seconds change to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.title = currentTitle;
}, 5000);
```